# Remove unused Images/files from upload folder laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have **laravel5.4** application.I want to remove unused **images/files** from my upload folder which is not available in my database.

For example : 
I have 50 images in my upload folder for user profile but some of the image not use for any user.i think he removed or update his image from frontend.

Yes i know we need to code to remove file when user update or remove profile picture at a time also delete from upload folder.but my app run from many time and i want to remove unused file using script not manually beacause i have lot's of files so it's hard to check and remove file manually.anyone can you please help me for create any function for remove file from folder.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: An easy solution is to save the currents user image path in the `users` table. If a users updates his image you can delete the current image and store the image in the filesystem and the new path in the `users` table

Comment: But I want to remove an old image which is not available any user because user updates it early.Do you get my point?

Comment: Ah okay then my solution is more to prevent problems like this in the future. Where do you store which user uses which image

Comment: i story only image name in my database and add this image in my public/upload folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use something like this in my AdminController to remove images by clicking on a button.
Maybe you need to change the path or extensions

```
public function deleteUnusedImages()
{
    $file_types = [
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
    ];
    $directory = public_path();
    $files = File::allFiles($directory);
    
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $file_types)) {
            
            if(DB::table('users')->where('votes', '=', $file)->count())
                continue; // continue if the picture is in use
            
            echo 'removed' . basename($file)."<br />";
            unlink($file); // delete if picture isn't in use
        }
    }
}
```